# We are proud to announce

Tags: sentence-structure

How do you natives say the following sentence; I guess it should be said in another way, but I do not know how:

**We are proud to announce our readiness for manufacturing any type of toys.**

PS: I need to write this sentence at the end of a very official letter.

Comment: What troubles you about the sentence you've written? Are you unsure about the use of the word proud or do you have some other concern?

Comment: It is a sort of scruple. I need to know whether a native write such a concept in the way I wrote it or not. I doubt about it.

Comment: This is probably opinion based, but my preference for sounding natural would be "We are proud to announce our readiness *to manufacture* any type of toys.

Comment: The word you're looking for here is "idiomatic" -- your sentence isn't idiomatically correct when it's correct in every grammatical and contextual regard, but it uses colloquialisms improperly, or words in ways unusual to a native speaker. Obviously you've also realized that language learners gain the intuition for seeing idiomatic errors before they know exactly how to solve them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"We are proud to announce our readiness for manufacturing" is an awkward phrase for a couple of reasons; it's long-winded, and appends a lot of two-word phrases to each other ("to announce," "our readiness," "for manufacturing") which can be awkward to say.

Also, as @Jim pointed out below, you had a minor grammatical error at the end; "any" is to be used with a singular noun, so "toys" should be "toy."

One possible way to re-write this sentence would be like this:

> We are proud to announce that we are ready to manufacture any type of toy.

This separates the sentence into two very distinct clauses separated by the word "that" instead of a run-on of two-word phrases, which is much more agreeable to a native speaker like myself. However, you said the letter was official, and "ready" sounds a bit informal to me. I might end up writing the sentence like this, if I were writing the letter:

> We are proud to announce that we are prepared to manufacture any type of toy.

Prepared can be used as a synonym for "ready" and connotes a much more formal style.

Comment: I might add that it should be either *any type of toy* or *all types of toys*

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, I completely missed that!